# Edit a rotated object normally?

Tags: camera, edit-mode, object-mode

(first off I know that I'm using the old Blender, I will switch soon. Functionalities will probably be the same though). I have this object that I rotated 20 degrees in object mode:

[image]

However, I would like to edit it with zero rotation, like this:

[image]

How can I do that? Can I perhaps align the camera with its rotation? Any help would be nice :)

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change this value to "0", should reset it to flat.

### Edit: option to leave it rotated normally, and edit at 0 degrees

If you add an empty, then set the object with a "copy rotation" constraint;

[image]

Then you can apply the rotation of the empty to the object, regardless of where they're located relative to each other.

Also, you can "hide" (disable) or "show" (enable) the rotation at-will with this icon here;

[image]

Comment: alright, thank you :)

Comment: If this is the method that worked for you, please mark is at the Accepted Answer for future users